# Zebra Stripping with phpspreadsheet

Tags: php, laravel, phpspreadsheet

I was looking around for examples and/or guides on how to use phpspreadsheet's conditional formatting. Specifically looking so that I could zebra stripe my spreadsheet in a way that allows for resorting of the sheet. I came up very empty with only a few spotty SO questions using the old PHPExcel library and just one example from the documentation. Given that zebra stripes are pretty common style to apply I was mildly outraged that I couldn't find a copy/paste job. So I figured it out myself and now will leave it here for posterity and hopefully myself in a few years.

I am actually going to spell out a lot more as I have used phpspreadsheet for a few years now and out of the box the defaults don't really give you a nice looking spreadsheet. I will also note I do not care how it looks; its just data to me but, my bosses must have quality formatting.

Answer (score 1):

**Zebra Stripping**

```
$range = 'A3:'.$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getHighestDataColumn.
               $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getHighestDataRow();
$conditional1 = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Conditional();
$conditional1->setConditionType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Conditional::CONDITION_EXPRESSION)
              ->setOperatorType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Conditional::OPERATOR_EQUAL)
              ->addCondition('MOD(ROW(),2)=0');
$conditional1->getStyle()->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)
             ->getStartColor()->setARGB('DFDFDF');
$conditional1->getStyle()->getFill()->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)
             ->getEndColor()->setARGB('DFDFDF');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($range)->setConditionalStyles([$conditional1]);
```

The range starts at A3 because I have a logo in row 1 and headers in row 2. Also you can apply as many conditions as you need which is why the final setConditionalStyles is wrapped in an array.

**Freeze 1 columns and  2 rows**

```
$sheet->freezePane('B2');
```

This will freeze that cell B2 and everything to the left and above. Super helpful for long and wide sheets letting you keep your primary_key and headers in view at all times.

**Insert Logo in 1st cell**

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->insertNewRowBefore(1, 1);
$drawing = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing();
$drawing->setCoordinates('A1');
$drawing->getShadow()->setVisible(true);
$drawing->setName({{alt text}});
$drawing->setPath(resource_path().{{filepath}});
$drawing->setWorksheet($spreadsheet->getActiveSheet());
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('1')->setRowHeight(55);
```

**Hiding a sheet**

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setSheetState('veryHidden');
```

This is one thing I really like to do as I have written some automation that relies on a user making
edits to a spreadsheet and returning the sheet to a specific email address that I can access via api and download and reprocess based on the edits to the sheet. I use this mainly for storing information our erp needs to access records such as a customer_id or contract_number so that when the sheet comes back I don't have to re-query ident info I can just grab it from the hidden sheet. Bonus of using very hidden is a normal user can't unhide it unless they know enough to open the dev window and get in VB script.

**Put Filters on all headers**

```
$dimensions = 'A2' . ':' . $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getHighestDataColumn() . 
                           $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getHighestDataRow();
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setAutoFilter($dimensions);
$autoFilter = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getAutoFilter();
$autoFilter->showHideRows();
```

The trick on this one is the last line it won't actually apply the filters until there is some kind of action so I just grabbed a random function that wouldn't have any effect on my sheet.

**Auto Width Columns**

```
$colNumber = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate::columnIndexFromString(
             $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getHighestDataColumn);
for ($col = 1; $col <= $colNumber; $col++) {
    $colAlpha = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate::stringFromColumnIndex($col);
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($colAlpha)->setAutoSize(true);
}
$sheet->calculateColumnWidths();
```

**Making Spreadsheets with multiple tabs**

First let me note I have come up with a somewhat standard structure I use whenever I make a spreadsheet and then I feed it through one function that does all of the above things. So here is my standard.

```
$report = json_encode([
        'filepath' => 'Program Size/',
        'filename' => $customer_name->company_name.' Program Size '.Carbon::parse('now')->format('Ymd').'.xlsx',
        'Type' => 'buildMultiSheet',
        '1' => [
            'request' => [
                'TabName' => 'Program Size',
                'header' => array_keys($source[0]),
                'body' => $source,
                'formatArray'=> [
                    'aboveHeader'=>['Total Value:',$sum],
                    'zebra' => 'stripe',
                    'F:G' => '"$"#,##0.00_-'
                ]
            ]
        ],
        '2' => [
            'request' => [
                'TabName' => 'config_sheet',
                'header' => [],
                'body' => $queryLog,
                'formatArray'=> [
                    'hidden'=> 1
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]);
```

This structure has every thing you need to make a spreadsheet with multiple tabs. Source for me is generally the result of a DB call. This isn't complete detail for example a tabname longer than 31 characters will freak out so you have to check for it. One of these days I might tidy things up and publish a package to go along side phpspreadsheet but, we  will see if/when that ever happens.

```
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$filename = $requestD["filename"];
unset($requestD["filename"]);
$filepath = $requestD["filepath"];
unset($requestD["filepath"]);
$tabCounter = 0;
$spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex($tabCounter);
        
foreach ($requestD as $tab) {
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $body = $tab["request"]["body"];  
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($tab["request"]["TabName"]);
    $headers = $tab["request"]["header"];
    $sheet->fromArray($headers, NULL, 'A1');
    $sheet->fromArray($body, NULL, 'A2', false);  

    //processing here, sheet formatting , etc.
        
    $tabCounter++;
    $spreadsheet->createSheet();
    $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex($tabCounter);
}
    
//remove last empty sheet before resetting index
$spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$spreadsheet->removeSheetByIndex($tabCounter);
```

Well that's all the tips I have. If I have done anything really dumb please do let me know how I can improve.